# Python strip unexpected behavior

Tags: python

I was stripping a file name in python for routing purposes and I was getting some unexpected behavior with the python strip function. I've read the docs and searched online but have not been able to find an explanation for the following behavior:

```
"Getting-Started.md".strip('.md')
 Out[29]: 'Getting-Starte'
```

But if it is any other character aside from 'd' to the left of the period, it works properly:

```
"Getting-StarteX.md".strip('.md')
 Out[30]: 'Getting-StarteX'
```

It seems like there is something similar to a mirroring going on 'd. md'. I'm doing a double strip to get by this for now, but I was just curious of why this occurs.

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*`strip()` would strip all the characters provided in the argument* - in your case `.`, `m` and `d`.

Instead, you can use [`os.path.splitext()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext):

```
import os
os.path.splitext("Getting-StarteX.md")[0]
```

Comment: the last one is the preferred one.

Comment: @Daniel agreed, removed other options to avoid confusion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one ".md" appearing at the end of the testing string, you can also use

```
"Getting-Started.md".split('.md')[0]
```

Thanks @Carpetsmoker remind me the assumption.

Comment: `.split('.md')`? Are you sure? Also, what if my file is named `this.is.a.markdown.file.md`?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker, you are right.  There have to be an assumption that there is only one ".md" at the end of the testing string.

Comment: Why not `'.'.join("Get.ting-Sta.rted.md".split('.')[:-1])` ;-)

Comment: Sooner or later someone *will* use a `.` in a filename and will confuse you because it'll say "file not found" even though the file *is right there*! ;-) Bugs are even less elegant!

Comment: If you want to go this route (IMO you should not), you should be using `.rsplit('.md', 1)[0]`